# Batch file to close program after second program opens

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a frontend program (a.exe) that I use to curate and launch other programs (in this example b.exe). Once the item in the frontend (a.exe) is selected from the list (b.exe) launches. Problem is the frontend (a.exe) stays open and to close it I have to manually exit out of the program it launched (b.exe) to the desktop to do so.

What I am trying to do is have the frontend (a.exe) close after an item within it is selected (b.exe). This would be trigged by a double click.

How would I go about creating a batch file to do this?

The frontend program (a.exe) has a GUI interface.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\a.exe folder"
start a.exe
```

then what?

Comment: I will make your suggested change but I don't have any problems launching "a.exe" with a batch file with the above code. What I want to accomplish is that after "a.exe" launches "b.exe" through the interface by double clicking it, “a.exe” will automatically close without having to manually intervene.

Comment: I understand your requirement. But the code of `a.exe` must be changed to run the application `b.exe` detached and not with waiting until `b.exe` terminates itself as it currently does. It would be of course possible to write in batch file a loop which checks periodically in intervals of 1 second if `b.exe` is found in Windows task list with `tasklist` and then kill `a.exe` with `taskkill`. But that does not make sense in my point of view because then the batch file should simply start `b.exe` directly without obviously unnecessary `a.exe`.

Comment: The solution you propose would do the job I am seeking. The reason "a.exe" needs to be run first is that it's a frontend that contains different configurations for each program that is launched from it. If "b.exe" is simply launched by tiself then it is done so with a default configuration and will crash.

Comment: I suggest to use free tool [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from Sysinternals (Microsoft). Process Explorer is an enhanced task manager. After extracting the ZIP file to a folder of your choice on a local drive, starting it, confirming the EULA (Microsoft!), start `a.exe` and next `b.exe`. Then right click on `b.exe` in Process Explorer and left click on `Properties`. You can see the command line used to start `b.exe` and on tab `Environment` the environment variables set on starting `b.exe`.

Comment: Now write a batch file creating the same environment for `b.exe`, i.e. set the environment variables which are set/modified by `a.exe` and not defined by default as it can be seen on running command `set` in a command prompt window and start with command `start` the executable `b.exe` with the same command line as `a.exe` does it. Then the usage of `a.exe` should be no longer needed to run `b.exe`.

Comment: This isn't a matter of removing the use of a.exe though. It's a frontend that is still very much necessary because b.exe as used in my example is not the only program it launches. There are literally 30 different programs that launch from a.exe, many with different configurations that are pre-set with a.exe. The best solution is still your previous mention of having a loop that checks for b.exe/c.exe/d.exe etc and then closes a.exe once any of them are detected as running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be contacting the author of `a.exe` and asking for an option to automatically exit `a.exe` after starting application `b.exe` as separate and detached process.

The second best solution would be finding out which environment `b.exe` needs to run successfully and create with a batch file this environment and start `b.exe`.

However, if the best two solutions are not possible for whatever reason, then the following batch file code be helpful.

```
@echo off
start "" /D"C:\Program Files\a.exe folder" "a.exe"
set "LoopCount=0"

:Loop
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /C:"b.exe" /C:"c.exe" /C:"d.exe" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM "a.exe"
    goto EndBatch
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /C:"a.exe"
if errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch
set /A LoopCount+=1
if not %LoopCount% == 60 goto Loop

:EndBatch
set "LoopCount="
```

The batch file first starts `a.exe` with its program files directory set as current directory before starting it as separate process.

Windows command processor immediately continues execution of the batch file after starting `a.exe` and defines next the environment variable `LoopCount` with value `0`.

Inside the loop the external command **TIMEOUT** available since Windows Vista by default is used to wait one second.

Then external command **TASKLIST** is executed to output all running processes without header. This output is redirected with `|` to external command **FINDSTR** which searches *case-sensitive* at beginning of all lines output by **TASKLIST** for one of the strings specified with the option `/C:`. For a case-insensitive search use additionally **FINDSTR** option `/I` if not knowing how the executables started by `a.exe` are in list output by **TASKLIST**.

**FINDSTR** exits with value `0` on having found at least one line starting with one of the searched strings and with value `1` if nothing matched. The output of **FINDSTR** is of no interest and therefore redirected to device **NUL**.

The terminate signal is sent with external command **TASKKILL** to the executable `a.exe` on having found one of the processes in the list. `a.exe` should terminate itself on receiving and processing this signal. In case of `a.exe` is ignoring this signal or it terminates, but before terminates also the started application, it would be necessary to use additionally the **TASKKILL** option `/F` to force a real kill of `a.exe` process by the Windows operating system. In general the option `/F` should not be used as it can result in corrupt files in case of application killed by the operating system has one or more files open for write operations.

But if after one second none of the processes started by `a.exe` is running, the batch file checks next if `a.exe` itself is still running. The batch file exits if this is not the case. Otherwise it increments the environment variable `LoopCount` and compares its value with `60` to exit batch file after having waited already 60 seconds with the checks to avoid a nearly endless running batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`

See also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Finally had a chance to mess around with this further and your batch code worked beautifully. Thanks for your help. You are a gentleman.